# How to use git to record the modification history of blog posts in building a blog website?

Tags: java, git

I found out that SO can record the history of modifying questions.

[image: Edit Record Screenshot]

I want to build a blog with a function to view and record the modification history of all blog posts.

Git has the function of recording the modification history of files.

**How should I combine Git and Java to achieve this functionality? Or shouldn't Git be used for this functionality?**

Any ideas can help me, thanks.

Comment: _"Git has the function of recording the modification history of files"_ funnily enough it doesn't. It takes snapshots of files, and the diffs are calculated dynamically.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry, I misunderstood Git. But if git saves each snapshot, doesn't it need to consume a lot of storage space?

Comment: Not really since it uses very efficient compression algorithms. This is also why we don't store binaries, or similar files, in git without using git-lfs.

Comment: @SageJustus "*…if git saves each snapshot, doesn't it need to consume a lot of storage space?*" Quite a common misunderstanding. Git actually never saves copies of identical files — it stores references to previous files.

Comment: @phd Are the `identical files` you mean the exact same files? If only one line is different, is it `identical files`?

Comment: @SageJustus No, identical files must be identical. One line different — and Git stores the different files under different addresses in its DB. But again, it employs tricks to lower required disk space. Sometimes it stores full blobs and sometimes it optimizes storage by storing only difference (deltas).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to reinvent the wheel here. There is an offering called [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), which allows you to create a blog using markdown files. Under the hood, the static site generator https://jekyllrb.com (Ruby) converts the markdown files to HTML. You manage all the blog files with `git`, tracking changes over time of course. Push an update to your production branch, then relative files are generated and pushed live.

There's also a static site generator built with Java called https://jbake.org. You can view the source code for that, which should give you some insight into how to accomplish what you're describing.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. But I also can't use a pure blogging framework, because I actually want to integrate this functionality in my Java project. Can you briefly talk about `https://jbake.org`'s requirement for keeping historical records, and what technology does it use?

Comment: I've no idea about JBake, it's just the first Java-based project I found while looking for something like Jekyll.